# 'str' object is not callable Python

Tags: python, string

Return True if and only if the person's age is greater than 50 or
they have a Access Card as indicated by has_access_card.

Here is my program:

```
def bypass_line(age, has_access_card):
    if age >50 or has_access_card ("yes"):
        return True
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: How are you *calling* this function? We need more context. `has_access_card` is a string here, but where that came from is not visible.

Comment: what is has_access_card ?

Comment: "or they have a Access Card as indicated by has_access_card"

Comment: can you include the calling code?

Answer (score 3):

`has_access_card` is a string and you're trying to call it like a function, what with the parentheses that follow it.

I'm pretty sure that you mean `has_access_card == "yes"` instead.

An even better approach might be to pass `True` or `False` rather than strings, or, if you must pass a string (for example because it's user input), use `has_access_card.lower().startswith("y")` to be the most tolerant of what might be passed in.

Comment: +1, I was thinking the same about what the OP meant.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, `has_access_card` is a string.  If so, then putting `(...)` after it will make Python try to call it as a function.  Strings can't be called like functions, so you get an error.

I think what you really meant was this:

```
def bypass_line(age, has_access_card):
    if age > 50 or has_access_card == "yes":
        return True
```

This method sees if `has_access_card` equals `"yes"`.